# Undefined Reference to class static member in static member

Tags: c++, static, undefined-reference, self-reference

I am creating a linked list with self referential class in C++ and I want to have a static pointer of the type Item (Item is the class name) named "startPointer" so that when i call my static member function "free" , it can free up the memory by using Item::startPointer but i am getting an error(shown after code). Pls Help,

```
class Item
{
    public:
    std::string name;
    int row,column;
    int fileType;
    Item *ptr;
    static Item *startPointer;
    void setNextPointer(Item* ptr)
    {
        ptr=ptr;
    }
    Item *getNextPointer()
    {
        return ptr;
    }
    static void free()
        {
        Item *p,*temp;
        p=startPointer;
        while(p!=NULL)
        {
            temp=p;
            p=p->getNextPointer();
            delete temp;
        }
    }

};
```

---

```
cube.o:cube.cpp:(.text$_ZN4Item4freeEv[Item::free()]+0x8): undefined reference to `Item::startPointer'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

mingw32-make.exe: *** [cube.exe] Error 1

Execution terminated
```

Comment: You should read about cosntructors, destructors and RAII.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Answer (score 4):

You have to define your static member like this:

```
Item* Item::startPointer = nullptr; // or = NULL; if your cpp version is below c++11
```

Write such a line in a single compilation unit (cpp file), otherwise the member is just declared.

Comment: `nullptr` with `C++11`

Comment: @P0W I think standart adaption is far enough than we can assume that one uses c++11 if not saying otherwise. IMO its better to show code how it is supposed to be written and not how it has been written before.